# Android reading from text file

Tags: java, android, text-files

So I have this code as well as a text file in MyApplicationProject/assets. I am trying to read it and put it into a 2d array splited by line and by ',' I keep getting IOException. Thank you in advance

```
    public String[][] stopData() throws IOException {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream input;

        input = assetManager.open("stops.txt");

        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();


        String content = new String(buffer);
        String[] lines = content.split("/n");
        String[][] stopData = new String[lines.length][];

        for (int i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            stopData[i] = lines[i].split(",");
            if (stopData[i].length != 9 ) {
                Log.d(TAG,"odd length " + stopData.toString() );
            }
        }
    return stopData;
}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace with the error description. It sure explains the problem in your code.

Comment: You should not read a file that way. If the file is huge, you can't read it in one single pass, you need to loop, filling a small array with data from the file and adding the result to some object in memory. 

Moreover, your exception management is really bad, you should use 2 try catch blocks to read a file. 

You can find some much better examples on the web easily.

All this is the right technique, some libraries make it much easier. Google apache commons io : IOUtils.toString(InputStream in)